# How to solve SQL ERROR 1064 SQL STATE 42000

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a Order POJO and a table 'order' in mysql database. I am using hibernate to populate the table. I have a struts2 form in which there are three select tags. I get `SQL ERROR 1064 SQL STATE 42000` and when using the debugger in the variables view I find that the `comp` is always `null`

Order POJO:

```
    public class Order {

    public int id;
    public int poNumber;
    public String orderType;
    public String poDate;
    public String poDeliveryDate;
    public String exciseDuty;
    public String salesTax;
    public String remark;
    public String deliverySchedule;
    public String comp;

    public Order(){}

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPoNumber(){
        return poNumber;
    }

    public void setPoNumber(int poNumber){
        this.poNumber = poNumber;
    }

    public String getOrderType(){
        return orderType;
    }

    public void setOrderType(String orderType){
        this.orderType = orderType;
    }

    public String getPoDate(){
        return poDate;
    }

    public void setPoDate(String poDate){
        this.poDate = poDate;
    }

    public String getPoDeliveryDate(){
        return poDate;
    }

    public void setPoDeliveryDate(String poDeliveryDate){
        this.poDeliveryDate = poDeliveryDate;
    }

    public String getExciseDuty(){
        return poDate;
    }

    public void setExciseDuty(String exciseDuty){
        this.exciseDuty = exciseDuty;
    }

    public String getSalesTax(){
        return salesTax;
    }

    public void setSalesTax(String salesTax){
        this.salesTax = salesTax;
    }

    public String getRemark(){
        return remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark){
        this.remark = remark;
    }

    public String getDeliverySchedule(){
        return deliverySchedule;
    }

    public void setDeliverySchedule(String deliverySchedule){
        this.deliverySchedule = deliverySchedule;
    }

    public String getComp(){
        return comp;
    }

    public void setComp(String comp){
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    public String execute(){
        OrderManager.placeOrder(this);
        return "success";
    }

}
Stack Trace:00:07:22,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
00:07:22,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
00:07:22,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started in 9282ms - Started 301 of 339 services (59 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
00:10:01,848 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
00:10:01,857 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
00:10:01,861 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
00:10:01,864 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
00:10:01,893 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
00:10:01,893 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
00:10:01,962 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Company.hbm.xml
00:10:02,191 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Order.hbm.xml
00:10:02,274 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
00:10:02,386 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
00:10:02,388 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/purchaseorder]
00:10:02,389 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root}
00:10:02,390 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
00:10:02,392 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
00:10:02,893 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
00:10:03,010 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
00:10:03,017 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
00:10:03,088 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1
00:10:03,698 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
00:10:03,698 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order' at line 1
00:10:03,702 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) SQL Warning Code: 1064, SQLState: 42000
00:10:03,703 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order' at line 1
00:10:03,707 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Exception occurred during processing request: could not extract ResultSet: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator.initializePreviousValueHolder(IncrementGenerator.java:132) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator.generate(IncrementGenerator.java:69) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at buhinGroup.OrderManager.placeOrder(OrderManager.java:21) [classes:]
    at buhinGroup.Order.execute(Order.java:100) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:870) [ognl-3.0.6.jar:]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293) [ognl-3.0.6.jar:]
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68) [ognl-3.0.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1369) [ognl-3.0.6.jar:]
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90) [ognl-3.0.6.jar:]
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212) [ognl-3.0.6.jar:]
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258) [ognl-3.0.6.jar:]
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494) [ognl-3.0.6.jar:]
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458) [ognl-3.0.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2.execute(OgnlUtil.java:309) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:340) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:307) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:423) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:287) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:250) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99) [struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2313) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    ... 97 more

`
`
```

Comment: Order is a reserved keyword in sql.

Comment: Why did you declare comp surrounded with pointer refs?

Comment: @avk No actually I wanted to give it a bold look. now i have edited it

Answer (score 2):

Look at Aleksandr's comment. Also in log:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order' at line 1
```